# Nx workspace + Nest.js: separate bundle for each library

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, nrwl-nx

My problem is that whenever I run `nx build api` I get a single `main.js` which includes everything in my monorepo. What I want is my libraries having their own `.js` bundles. It can be clearly seen here [angular-spotify](https://github.com/trungk18/angular-spotify.git) . If you compile the project, you will see that each library has own bundle file. Here is what it looks like: [example dist folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8N1M.png).

I also made an example repo showing my problem here: [example repo](https://github.com/lasagna-coder/test-bundle). As you can see, all I have is `main.js` file, despite having also `shared` module, which is supposed to have its own bundle file.

My goal ultimately is being able to use typeorm migration feature with typescript. My typeorm entities are TS files which located in a separate lib, but `migration` works only with JS entities. Thus I need to compile my TS entities (which include imports from other libs) to JS files and specify folder in the `dist` in `ormconfig.json` like this `dist/entities/*.js`. But it is not possible if I only have bare `main.js` as output file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you get this to work? Im looking to do something similar

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm running in the same issue